# Separate the multiple ipv6 addresses

Tags: proxy, ipv6

I have a vps that comes with 16 ipv6. I used one of the addresses and I tried testing the proxy at http://ipv6-test.com/ but it detected that is using the first ipv6 adddress instead of the certain ipv6 address that I provided.

Example I used 2607:f358:0001:fed5:0022:772f:6ed3:7f3c as my proxy but it detected as 2607:f358:0001:fed5:0022:0000:db61:85e1 . Why is it doing that?

The proxy server I am using is polipo

Comment: What program are you using to do the proxy?

Comment: I am using polipo

Answer (score 0):

It does that because your proxy is not explicitly binding to a specific address when initiating a new outbound connection. The kernel must choose one. Operating systems may vary on how it chooses the preferred/default address.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. How do you bind all my 16 ipv6 addresses? so I can use them as proxies

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the config assuming you are using polipo as I gleamed from above.

> proxyAddress = "IP address you want it to listen on."

http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~jch/software/polipo/polipo.html#Client-connections

Comment: I added my ipv6 address but I get a connection reset but if I use :: as the unspecific address it'll work. It doesn't seem to work when I put one of the 16 addresses

Comment: What are you using to configure your proxy? What settings are you using?